# Get tagged user_id tagged on video using facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get tagged user_ids from Facebook Graph api. I have successfully done that for photo using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/photo_id/tags
```

this gives me the user_ids tagged in the photo.

when i tried to use this for video

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v_id/tags
```

This gives me empty result.

Suggest me a way to get video tagged user-ids either via FQL or Graph api.

Thanks
'

Comment: [Videos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) don't have tag connection. Check if you can get tags on `video_id` output itself as it is passed as key value pair in JSON

Comment: ya i know videos don't have tags connection. I can get tags from the output but it will be max 25 and there will be paging info but no count info. so, i was wondering if there is any fql query so that i can get tags count on video, as it may be some thousands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement you can look into the [`video_tag`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video_tag) FQL table which can get you the necessary details. Quoting from documentation

> An FQL table containing information about a video tag. The video_tag table can be used to find all users tagged in a specific video, or all videos that a user has been tagged in. video_tag uses the same visibility constraints as video, so a user can see a video tag if and only if that user can see the video itself.

You can perform query against video id and retrieve the tag data